# SQL Pivot and Partition And Generate ID

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot, window-functions

I need help with creating a SQL Pivot and generating a unique ID column in the process, please.

I am working on SQL Server.

In the digram below I have displayed the source data.
I need to pivot the data into another table, the data comes in pairs of 'Fail' and 'Pass' and I need to pivot the time at which they Failed and then passed.

I also need to have a unique ID field generated for each pivoted record - I have named this column GENERATE-ID in the diagram below.

[Figure 1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc4cx.png)

I have created a SQL script for the test data:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TestDataForPivot](
    [Location] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [DateTimeStamp] [datetime] NULL,
    [Result] [varchar](100) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestDataForPivot] ([Location], [DateTimeStamp], [Result]) VALUES (N'A001', CAST(N'2023-03-01T10:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Fail')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestDataForPivot] ([Location], [DateTimeStamp], [Result]) VALUES (N'A001', CAST(N'2023-03-01T10:10:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Pass')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestDataForPivot] ([Location], [DateTimeStamp], [Result]) VALUES (N'A002', CAST(N'2023-03-01T14:00:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Fail')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestDataForPivot] ([Location], [DateTimeStamp], [Result]) VALUES (N'A002', CAST(N'2023-03-01T14:20:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Pass')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestDataForPivot] ([Location], [DateTimeStamp], [Result]) VALUES (N'A002', CAST(N'2023-03-01T14:30:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Fail')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestDataForPivot] ([Location], [DateTimeStamp], [Result]) VALUES (N'A002', CAST(N'2023-03-01T15:30:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Pass')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestDataForPivot] ([Location], [DateTimeStamp], [Result]) VALUES (N'A003', CAST(N'2023-03-01T20:30:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Fail')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestDataForPivot] ([Location], [DateTimeStamp], [Result]) VALUES (N'A003', CAST(N'2023-03-01T20:35:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Pass')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestDataForPivot] ([Location], [DateTimeStamp], [Result]) VALUES (N'A001', CAST(N'2023-03-01T20:30:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Fail')
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TestDataForPivot] ([Location], [DateTimeStamp], [Result]) VALUES (N'A001', CAST(N'2023-03-02T11:10:00.000' AS DateTime), N'Pass')
GO
```

I have tried to do a pivot myself but I am not being able to get the result.
I am not sure how to generate the ID column and also with the pivot only one row is being generated where LOCATION = A002 - because ont he pivot I am having to use an agregate function of MIN or MAX

I hope you can help me out.

Comment: Can you show what you tried? Also explain what should happen if there is only a fail, only a pass, two fails and one pass, two passes and one fail, when the pass comes before the fail, etc.

Comment: Thank you Aaron. I have been trial and error and sorry but my SQL is way off. 

To answer your question, there should always be a fail and if there is no time-value for a Pass then it should remain null. 

It is no longer letting me post the SQL in the comment saying it is too long - but I am way off with the SQL

Comment: But what about the other questions? What if there are two fails, two passes etc? Please [edit] your question using the [edit] button and explain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If everything is correct, it will work. If the other state is different from your output, state it so that the code is complete

```
select 1000 +ROW_NUMBER() over(order by (select 0))as  Genetate_ID,
[Location],[DateTimeStamp] as FAil,

lgDateTimeStamp as PAss

from (
select *,lead([DateTimeStamp]) over(partition by [Location] order by [DateTimeStamp]) as lgDateTimeStamp
,lead([Result]) over(partition by [Location] order by [DateTimeStamp]) as lgResult
from [TestDataForPivot]
)a
where lgResult='Pass' and Result='Fail'
order by [DateTimeStamp]
```

Result:

| Genetate_ID | Location | FAil | PAss |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | A001 | 2023-03-01 10:00:00.000 | 2023-03-01 10:10:00.000 |
| 1002 | A002 | 2023-03-01 14:00:00.000 | 2023-03-01 14:20:00.000 |
| 1003 | A002 | 2023-03-01 14:30:00.000 | 2023-03-01 15:30:00.000 |
| 1004 | A003 | 2023-03-01 20:30:00.000 | 2023-03-01 20:35:00.000 |
| 1005 | A001 | 2023-03-01 20:30:00.000 | 2023-03-02 11:10:00.000 |

Comment: _Note this is missing a row for the edge case where a fail occurs but it hasn't passed yet; [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/CFO80Efe)._

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, possibly:

```
SELECT [GENERATE-ID] = 1000 + ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Fail),
  Location, Fail, Pass
FROM 
(
  SELECT Location, 
    Fail =      CASE Result WHEN 'Fail' THEN DateTimeStamp END,
    Pass = LEAD(CASE Result WHEN 'Pass' THEN DateTimeStamp END, 1) 
           OVER (PARTITION BY Location ORDER BY DateTimeStamp)
  FROM dbo.TestDataForPivot
) AS x
WHERE Fail IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY Fail;
```

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/YpRH5DCx)

Based on comments, this will handle the case where a fail is missing a pass, but not the opposite.